# ORA-01440: column to be modified must be empty to decrease precision or scale

Tags: oracle

I have an Oracle table called Products. It has a ID column with the type of `NUMBER`.

I'd like to change its type to `Number(20, 0)` but it's giving me this error:

> ```
> ORA-01440: column to be modified must be empty to decrease precision or scale
> ```

So I've used this script:

```
alter table Products add ID_TEMP NUMBER(20,0);

update Products set ID_TEMP = ID;

update Products set ID = NULL;

alter table Products modify ID NUMBER(20,0);

update Products set ID = ID_TEMP;

alter table Products drop column ID_TEMP;
```

But it complains that

> ```
> cannot update ID to NULL
> ```

which is reasonable as it's a not nullable primary key.

How to change its datatype from `Number` to `Number(20, 0)`?

Comment: Drop the constraint? You might be better off with a CATS+rename, depending on exact circumstances.

Answer (score 8):

check whether ID IS A PRIMARY KEY.
If yes , you cannot modify it to nullable or insert NULL value to it..

so its better to do the following after doing  'UPDATE ID_TEMP WITH VALUES OF ID'

DROP THE ID COLUMN, AND ITS PRIMARY KEY CONSTRAINT.
RENAME THE COLUMN ID_TEMP TO ID
Then set the ID column to primary key. Example below :

```
 ALTER TABLE Products ADD ID_TEMP NUMBER(20,0);
 UPDATE PRODUCTS SET ID_TEMP = ID;
 ALTER TABLE PRODUCTS DROP COLUMN ID;
 ALTER TABLE PRODUCTS DROP CONSTRAINT ID_PK;
 ALTER TABLE PRODUCTS RENAME COLUMN PRODUCTS.ID_TEMP TO ID;
 ALTER TABLE PRODUCTS ADD CONSTRAINT ID_PK PRIMARY KEY (ID);
```

Comment: This happens whenever you want to remove a `NOT NULL` property. Generally this is the way to do, as your code looks like: make temporal column, copy everything, drop the original, create the original without the `NOT NULL` property, then copy back, drop the temporal column.

Comment: adding column syntax is wrong, keyword "COLUMN" is not required while adding a column to a table.